# com.github.chrisbanes.PhotoView and scaling an image by height

Tags: android, image

I am trying to use PhotoView and I would like the image to be shown like it is in Android's Wallpaper app.

So it seems that the images in the wallpaper app are scaled down or up to fill the of the screen, but the width is seemingly unchanged such that if you want to view the whole picture you either have to zoom or **scroll left and/or right**?  Is this making use of the setDisplayMatrix method? If so how would that method call look?  Here is a sample of my xml, but I am making use of Glide to set the image, if I need to drop Glide and just use the PhotoView widget directly I am will to do that too if that would produce the desired effect.

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                       android:id="@+id/photoView"
                                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                       tools:showIn="@layout/activity_wallpaper_viewer"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout spec for the photoview? Sounds like you want to fitcenter effect on your photoview?

Comment: @ShuZhang I don't think that would do it, won't fitCenter just scale the picture (down in my case because the images are large) to fit the whole image into the center of the screen.

Comment: how do you load the image with Glide. Glide has options for fitCenter(). centerCrop() would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Threw the image into a HorizontalScrollView, changed the xml a bit to this

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photoView" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Simple... Embarrassing...